# what value is written onto microcontroller pins if i send the value as character type in Embedded c program?

Tags: c, 8051

```
#include<reg51.h>
     sbit sw=P1^0;
     sbit led=P1^1;
    void write(unsigned char m);
     void delay(unsigned char k);

     void main(){
      while(1){ 
        delay(60);    
         sw=1;
         led=0;
         if(sw==1){
           delay(50);
           write(1);}
          else{
           delay(50);
           write(0);} 
           }}

           void write(unsigned char m){
              led=m;}

           void delay(unsigned char i)
           { unsigned int k,l;
           for(l=0;l<=i;l++)
           for(k=0;k<65500;k++);
           }
```

what value is received by write function whether it is character or integer? i want to send integer value to write on led? is it right?plz tell me

Comment: How is led defined?

Comment: why dont you use int instead of char.
It is possible you will get correct output.

Comment: led is defined as output pin

Comment: i want to use character for decreasing memory size as character requires 1 byte and interger requires 2 bytes

Comment: That is not a C primitive, so it leads to the next question: how is a pin defined?

Comment: P1^1 with name "led" using sbit as Output Pin for blinking led connected to p1.1 pin

Comment: You might need to check the compiler documentation. It's possible, for example, that assigning an integer type to an sbit results in the LSB of the integer being assigned to the sbit.

Comment: Not to get overly pedantic, but use the C99 defined types instead (uint8_t, int16_t): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` and `unsigned char` are numeric types; whatever value you assign to a variable of type `char` or `unsigned char` is the value that the variable will hold. So the `0` and `1` values in the two calls are fine.

Yes, C also uses `char` to represent character values, but that's a convenience: it doesn't affect what values are held. If you assign `1` to a `char` variable, the variable holds the value `1`. If you assign `'a'` to a `char` variable, the variable holds whatever value the `'a'` represents; these days it will be `97`, which is the ASCII representation for `'a'`.